# how disable to redis store auto session to db?

Tags: authentication, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

i store redis db with this code

```
   redisClientsManagerX = new PooledRedisClientManager("127.0.0.1:6379");
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => redisClientsManagerX);
   container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);


            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),  new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() }
  ));

            // Use a RedisAuthRepository
            var userRepo = new RedisAuthRepository(redisClientsManagerX);
            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepo);

            // Enable the RegistrationFeature
            Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

but, when i check redis db;
[image]

is there way to disable this auto iauthsessionstore disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to store the user profiles in Redis, and authenticate them using this source, but you don't want the active sessions to be stored in Redis? It is possible, though I am not sure it's a common scenario, see the warnings at the end of this answer.

## Change to the `MemoryCacheProvider`:

You can prevent the sessions from being stored to Redis by specifying the cache provider as a `MemoryCacheClient` rather than using the Redis cache client.

Change this line from:

```cs
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
```

To:

```cs
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => new MemoryCacheClient());
```

## Warnings:

- The session data will be stored in the memory of the ServiceStack application.
- If you are using IIS then IIS may recycle the application at anytime, and the cache contents will be lost.
- In memory caches such as this are localised to the server running the application, and therefore isn't suitable for server farms/clusters.

Comment: woow  wow wow.... after been hours try  and try...  you helped aagain :) you are the real hero dear Scott!! thanks alot :) you are really master on it and im so happy to get learn new things from you! happy Fridays mate :)

Comment: @user3790322 You're welcome. Glad it's helps. Have a good day too. :)

Comment: Thanks :) you prefer to store userauthsession? is it good thing? i wanted to disable it but i guess lots of user when login,  has lots of logs and get fill db.. thanks again bro :)

Comment: @user3790322 To keep track of the active user sessions ServiceStack must store a `userauthsession` for each session. It can do this in Redis or in another cache, such as the `MemoryCacheClient` which stores it in the memory of the application. The point is, in order to use ServiceStack's built in authentication you need this. Where you choose to store it is up to you, but from a scalability and reliability point of view, given that you have Redis, it's the safer choice.

Comment: @user3790322 I personally wouldn't log out to Redis if you have a restriction of the amount of storage you have. Logs are better stored in traditional databases that use disk space, rather than RAM, or log out to a file. Most people don't need instant access to logs.

Comment: wow , i noticed these great informations to my notebook, thanks so much :) this is my first step of service programming i been long years  development team but i really love it ss and redis :) these are pretty great informations so thanks :)